# Why C++ RTTI does not work as I expect it?

Tags: c++

**Note**: MRE example IS TOO BIG to publish it here(!), so I stored it on my google drive, here is a link - https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1BUDD2DhumdY2eVwO5BffyaQfjVIdABb3&export=download

I need to adjust very old lib which is using Xerces(1.6)/Xalan(1.3) to use new Xerces(3.2.5)/Xalan(1.12). Simply because it is almost impossible to build this code with modern Microsoft C++ compilers and STL.

To keep interface compatible I have to use a wrapper-class over some of Xerces/Xalan objects.
Wrapper store Xerces/Xalan objects as `void*` pointer. And I would like to add a type cast validation with RTTI. But something went wrong...

Here is a code for cast validation functions:

```
template<class T>
T* castAndCheck(const XmlLibObjectWrapper* pObjWrap)
{
  T* result = (T*)(pObjWrap->EngineObj);

#ifdef _CPPRTTI
  const type_info& ti = typeid(*result);
  const type_info& tiExpected = typeid(T);

  if (ti != tiExpected)
  {
    // I want it throw bad_cast here BUT IT DOES NOT!...
    //T& resultSpecific = dynamic_cast<T&>(*result); //<- this has the same problem
    T* resultSpecific = dynamic_cast<T*>(result);

    if (resultSpecific == NULL)
      throw XmlApiError(
        ParametrizedMessage("invalid type-cast: expect @1@ but got object of @2@ class")
        << tiExpected.name() << ti.name(),
        0, 0, CException::sl_Operational, _ERR_FLINE_);
  }
#endif

  return result;
}

DOMNode* castToDomNode(const XmlLibObjectWrapper* pObjWrap)
{
  return castAndCheck<DOMNode>(pObjWrap);
}

DOMElement* castToDomElement(const XmlLibObjectWrapper* pObjWrap)
{
  return castAndCheck<DOMElement>(pObjWrap);
}

XercesDOMParser* castToParser(const XmlLibObjectWrapper* pObjWrap)
{
  return castAndCheck<XercesDOMParser>(pObjWrap);
}
```

Here is a test case code:

```
// [...]
DOMDocument* dom = parser->getDocument();
// [...]
DOMElement* root = dom->getDocumentElement();
XmlLibObjectWrapper* wrp = new XmlLibObjectWrapper(root);
DOMNode* pn1 = castToDomNode(wrp);
DOMElement* pe1 = castToDomElement(wrp);
XercesDOMParser* xp = castToParser(wrp);
```

Unfortunately - there is no exceptions!
So, dynamic_cast<...> of DOMElement* to XercesDOMParser* does not see any problems in such cast!

Could you please advice - how can I organize type validation correctly?
If that is possible at all in such conditions (when ptr to lib object stored in a form of void*)?

**Note**: XmlLibObjectWrapper class is very simple, something like this:

```
class XmlLibObjectWrapper 
{
public:
  // Note: to remove XML lib dependencies we have to use void* here... 
  void* EngineObj;
}
```

Comment: You're `dynamic_cast`ing a `T*` to a `T*` ... That will not throw, and not return `nullptr` either.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: `if (ti != tiExpected)` should never be true... The type of `*result` is `T`. So `ti` and `tiExpected` both come from the type `T` and are equal.

Comment: @ChrisMM: yes. And that is weird that type_info shows different class names but dynamic_cast does not see any problems in it!

Comment: Note that `dynamic_cast<T*>( x )` when `x` is already a `T*` will not actually do any checks. You can compare the assembly of two `dynamic_cast`s here: https://godbolt.org/z/rK5xPvb7c

Comment: By the way, why are both `ti` and `tiExpected` references? That makes no sense.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: no, you mistaken! It got inside if (ti != tiExpected) without any problems, even for compatible (but not equal) classes. Ex: when casting DOMElement as DOMNode - it enters inside if (ti != tiExpected)

Comment: @Some programmer dude: I copy-pasted that code from Microsoft documentation - they recommend to use `const type_info&` for `typeid()`

Comment: The two alternatives I see then is related to the variables either being references, or `*result` is turned into a reference (i.e. `T&`).

Comment: @Toby Speight: it is quite difficult to add here a main() function! Because there would be a lot of code. I put here only the key-piece of code.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: as you can see in my code example there is a commented code line `//T& resultSpecific = dynamic_cast<T&>(*result); //<- this has the same problem` - it also does not work. :-(

Comment: @dmitry_bond  -- *And I would like to add a type cast validation* -- There is no mechanism in C++ that when given a `void *`, C++ knows what object was originally pointed to.  You have to know beforehand what it can point to and make the proper cast.

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class T>
T* castAndCheck(const XmlLibObjectWrapper* pObjWrap)
{
  T* result = (T*)(pObjWrap->EngineObj);
```

Don't use C-style casts.  This is a **reinterpret cast** here, quite probably.

If you do a reinterpret cast and it isn't a correct operation, your program will exhibit undefined behavior.  All bets are off.

For RTTI to work you have to start with a pointer to an object of a correct type, even if it is a base type.

`EngineObj` is a type you haven't told us, so I cannot directly fix your code.  If it is a `void*`, then there is no way to use RTTI to fix your problem.

Comment: I gave code example for `EngineObj` at the end of my question.

Comment: In such case C++ RTTI is a useless thing... :-( And unfortunately there is no common base class in Xerces/Xalan libs. So, seems it is impossible to do what I need. :-\ That sounds silly in 2023 year. Must be a way already.

Comment: Can't you just use a `variant` instead of `void*`?

Comment: @dmitry_bond "RTTI cannot do what I want in the way I want it" thus "it is useless" is a bad way to solve problems.  There may be ways to solve your problem that don't require RTTI to work in a way different than it does.  I have no idea what your problem constraints are; I can invent solutions, but in my experience that is a waste of time without problem constraints.  I do wonder why you have a single wrapper for a whole pile of different Xml library objects, and why it must store a `void*`, but all I can do is wonder.  Have you considered using a `std::any`?  That is a bad solution, but...

Comment: @WeijunZhou A variant would not let them hide the Xml library completely.  It is possible they have a system where they want to be be able to drop in and replace the Xml library?  And they are using these `XmlLibObjectWrapper` ad-hoc whereever the Xml library needs to store some state.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Then use your `super_any`. I really like it because it has the benefit of `std::any` and also has an interface to do something meaningful.

Comment: Idea of using `void*` is simple - this code derived from mainframe, so we cannot use any C++ headers and objects from Xerces/Xalan in our code. We only can use a wrapper lib which hides it from our code (because of OS limitation). And this solution was kept for years, even after we get rid of mainframe links. So, now we need to adjust this old lib to use new Xerces/Xalan... Thanks for hint with std::any - I will try...

Comment: I just tried std::any, unfortunately it seems does not support cast to derived classes. For example: if `void* p1 = std::any_cast<DOMElement*>(wrp->EngineObj);` works but for the same object `p1 = std::any_cast<DOMNode*>(wrp->EngineObj);` fail with "Bad any_cast" exception. :-\ So, in normal C++ cast DOMElement* to DOMNode* is valid but any_cast reports an error for it.

Comment: @dmitry_bond yes, `std::any` supports cast back to identical type, but is checked.  It might solve your problem with a bit of work on your part.  Odds are nothing solves your problem exactly.